# How in-memory databases persist data

Tags: database, in-memory-database

I was looking in to the concept of in-memory databases. Articles about that says,

> An in-memory database system is a database management system that stores data entirely in main memory.

and they discuss advantages and disadvantages of this concept.

My problem is if these database managements system that stores data entirely in main memory,

do all the data vanish after a power failure???

or are there ways to protect the data ???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most in-memory database systems offer persistence, at least as an option.  This is implemented through transaction logging.  On normal shutdown, an in-memory database image is saved.  When next re-opened, the previous saved image is loaded and thereafter, every transaction committed to the in-memory database is also appended to a transaction log file.  If the system terminates abnormally, the database can be recovered by re-loading the original database image and replaying the transactions from the transaction log file.

The database is still all in-memory, and therefore there must be enough available system memory to store the entire database, which makes it different from a persistent database for which only a portion is cached in memory.  Therefore, the unpredictability of a cache-hit or cache-miss is eliminated.

Appending the transaction to the log file can usually be done synchronously or asynchronously, which will have very different performance characteristics.  Asynchronous transaction logging will still risk the possibility of losing committed transactions if they were not flushed from the file system buffers and the system is shutdown unexpectedly (i.e. a kernel panic).

In-memory database transaction logging is guaranteed to only ever incur one file I/O to append the transaction to the log file.  It doesn't matter if the transaction is large or small, it's still just one write to the persistent media.  Further, the writes are always sequential (always appending to the log file), so even on spinning media the performance hit is as small as it can be.

Different media will have greater or lesser impact on performance. HDD will have the greatest, followed by SSD, then memory-tier FLASH (e.g. FusionIO PCIExpress cards) and the least impact coming from NVDIMM memory.

NVDIMM memory can be used to store the in-memory database, or to store the transaction log for recovery.  Maximum NVDIMM memory size is less than conventional memory size (and more expensive), but if your in-memory database is some gigabytes in size, this option can retain 100% of the performance of an in-memory database while also providing the same persistence as a conventional database on persistent media.

There are performance comparisons of an in-memory database with transaction logging to HDD, SSD and FusionIO in this whitepaper: http://www.automation.com/pdf_articles/mcobject/McObject_Fast_Durable_Data_Management.pdf

And with NVDIMM in this paper: http://www.odbms.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/IMDS-NVDIMM-paper.pdf

The papers were written by us (McObject), but are vendor-neutral.