# Content of in-memory h2-DB not visible in intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, h2

I use a in-memory H2-DB for a small demo-project.

I can connect to the DB through the h2-console and get access to the tables and their content. But actually I would prefer doing so directly in IntelliJ.

I managed the connection to the DB from the IDE, but can't see any tables. Why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

In comparison here the result in the h2-console:
[image]

Comment: Hit the third button that you can see, in your third picture which is refresh - anything changes?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605000/8370915) your question?

Comment: Yes indeed. This helped: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/testdb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER_PORT=10990